# how to create dataframe from hive external table

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, dataframe, hive, apache-spark-sql

we like to create the dataframe on top of Hive external table and use the hive schema and data for the computation in  spark level.

can we get the schema from the hive external table and use it as Dataframe schema.

Comment: I'm not completely sure but I think that it doesn't make any difference for Spark what kind of Hive table you have. As for schema, could you provide more details about data format you use in your Hive table?

Comment: We are having csv data files with out header and currently external file has created on this files , so we like to use the hive external table schema for creating the dataframes .

Comment: Have you considered accpeting an answer?

Comment: Have you thought about accepting an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark with Hive enabled can do this out of the box. Please reference the [docs.](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#running-sql-queries-programmatically)

```
val dataframe = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM table")
val schema = dataframe.schema
```

Comment: Raphael Roth provides a cleaner solution with `sqlContext.table(tablename)`

Answer (score 10):

The hive-metastore knows the schema of your tables and passes this information to spark. It does not matter whether the table is external or not:

```
val df = sqlContext.table(tablename)
```

where `sqlContext` is of type `HiveContext`. You can verify your schema with

```
df.printSchema
```

Comment: The same method works with a SparkSession too (I suspect enableHiveSupport() must be used when creating the SparkSession).

Answer (score 2):

To access the Hive table from Spark use Spark `HiveContext`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext;

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)
.
.
do other stuff..then
.
.

val data = sqlContext.sql("select * from hive_table");
```

here `data` will be your dataframe with schema of the Hive table.

Answer (score 1):

Load the data in data frame

```
df=sqlContext.sql("select * from hive_table")
```

Get schema with structTypes

```
df.schema
```

Get column Names of the Hive Table

```
df.columns
```

Get the column names with datatypes

```
df.dtypes
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create dataframe with tour own column name into `toDF()`

```
df = spark.sql("select * from table").toDF(col1,col2)
```